# Want to set value to input type text and then post the form to php from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, variables

id doesn't want to put the value in to the `document.getElementById("UniLoc").value = val;` and it doesn't want to submit the form how to fix this ?

This is how I call the function `JS` nas some value "asd56"

```
 echo "
 <script type="text/javascript">
    repostD("'.$JS.'");
 </script>";
```

here is my function inside

```
<script>
function repostD(val)
{   
   //document.getElementById("UniLoc").value = val;
   document.getElementById('UniLoc').innerHTML = val;
   //document.UlRL.UniLoc.value = val;
   document.forms["UlRL"].submit();
}
</script>
```

and here is my form in `html`

```
<form name="UlRL" id="UlRL" action="in.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="UniLoc" name="UniLoc" value="<?php echo $UniLoc;?>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doint that in php all instead of in function make an if clause down the code that will execute the action of the posting of the form and at the beggining of the php try this

```
 if($JS!="" )
 {

 $UniLoc=$JS;
 $JS="something that will go throught the other if down at the code";

  }
 else {

  $UniLoc=$_POST["UniLoc"];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById('UniLoc').value=val;
```

If there is nothing else wrong with your full form, it should submit. If you haven't closed your form tag, then close it.

```
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant really tell from your question what is wrong, but looking at your code:

```
document.getElementById('UniLoc').innerHTML=val;
```

you are trying to set the value of the input with id 'UniLoc', but you are using the wrong syntax. Instead of .innerHTML, use .value

```
document.getElementById('UniLoc').value=val;
```